# Extract one of multiple patterns from string column

Tags: regex, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, bigdata

I have a string column in a very large dataframe and I need to extract parts of the string based on several patterns. At this step, a single match is enough and I'm not looking to find all matching cases. This is an improvement request from a previous version that was using `regexp_extract` method for one pattern matching. The following code is working but is not very efficient considering the scale of data:

```
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [       
      ("file pattern1",),
      ("file pattern2",),
      ("file pattern3",)
  ],
  ['textCol'])
test = (sample_df
.withColumn("p1", F.regexp_extract(F.col('textCol'), pattern1, 1))
.withColumn("p2", F.regexp_extract(F.col('textCol'), pattern2, 1))
.withColumn("p3", F.regexp_extract(F.col('textCol'), pattern3, 1))
.withColumn("file", F.when(F.col("p1")!="", F.col("p1")).otherwise(F.when(F.col("p2")!="", F.col("p2")).otherwise(F.when(F.col("p3")!="", F.col("p3")).otherwise(""))))       
       )
```

Another way to work is `pandas_udf`. I have this function that is working, still, I prefer to keep it at Spark level for performance considerations.

```
@F.pandas_udf(returnType="string")
def get_file_dir(lines):
  res = []
  for l in lines:
    for r in reg_list:
      found=""
      m = re.search(r, l)
      if m:
        found=m.group(1)
        break
    res.append(found)
  return pd.Series(res)
```

I'm looking for any code optimization recommendations here that might help to reduce the runtime with my current cluster configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all the patterns together separated with a pipe `|`

```py
patterns = '|'.join([pattern1, pattern2, pattern3])
test = sample_df.withColumn('file', F.regexp_extract('textCol', patterns, 0))
```

Before:

```py
pattern1 = '(1$)'
pattern2 = '(\d\d)'
pattern3 = '(3$)'
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame([("file pattern1",), ("file pattern2",), ("file pattern3",)], ['textCol'])

test = (sample_df
    .withColumn("p1", F.regexp_extract(F.col('textCol'), pattern1, 1))
    .withColumn("p2", F.regexp_extract(F.col('textCol'), pattern2, 1))
    .withColumn("p3", F.regexp_extract(F.col('textCol'), pattern3, 1))
    .withColumn("file", F.when(F.col("p1")!="", F.col("p1")).otherwise(F.when(F.col("p2")!="", F.col("p2")).otherwise(F.when(F.col("p3")!="", F.col("p3")).otherwise(""))))       
)
test.show()
# +-------------+---+---+---+----+
# |      textCol| p1| p2| p3|file|
# +-------------+---+---+---+----+
# |file pattern1|  1|   |   |   1|
# |file pattern2|   |   |   |    |
# |file pattern3|   |   |  3|   3|
# +-------------+---+---+---+----+
```

After:

```py
pattern1 = '(1$)'
pattern2 = '(\d\d)'
pattern3 = '(3$)'
sample_df = spark.createDataFrame([("file pattern1",), ("file pattern2",), ("file pattern3",)], ['textCol'])

patterns = '|'.join([pattern1, pattern2, pattern3])
test = sample_df.withColumn('file', F.regexp_extract('textCol', patterns, 0))

test.show()
# +-------------+----+
# |      textCol|file|
# +-------------+----+
# |file pattern1|   1|
# |file pattern2|    |
# |file pattern3|   3|
# +-------------+----+
```

The changed version avoids several `withColumn` calls and nested `when`. It creates the result column in just one go.

Comment: I tried this way before, problem was that my regex patterns are more complex and I couldn't find a way to fix the same group number for all patterns. I will give this another try though as I'm now thinking maybe some reordering/priority might help. thanks